# helm template check for empty string

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have been asked to modify a Helm template to accommodate a few changes to check if a value is empty or not as in the code snippet below. I need to check `$var.alias` inside the `printf` in the code snippet and write custom logic to print a custom value. Any pointers around the same would be great.

```
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.testsConfig.keyVaults -}}
{{- range $secret, $var := $value.secrets -}}
{{- if nil $var.alias}}
{{- end -}}
{{ $args = append $args (printf "%s=/mnt/secrets/%s/%s" $var.alias $key $var.name | quote) }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Comment: I believe golang templating does not naturally distinguish between `nil` and `""`, so `{{ if $var.alias }}` should cover both cases; is that not your experience?

Answer (score 41):

I decided to test what madniel wrote in his comment. Here are my files:

values.yaml

```
someString: abcdef
emptyString: ""
# nilString:
```

templates/test.yaml

```
{{ printf "someEmptyString=%q)" .Values.someString }}
{{ printf "emptyString=%q)" .Values.emptyString }}
{{ printf "nilString=%q)" .Values.nilString }}

{{- if .Values.someString }}
{{ printf "someString evaluates to true" }}
{{- end -}}

{{- if .Values.emptyString }}
{{ printf "emptyString evaluates to true" }}
{{- end -}}

{{- if .Values.nilString }}
{{ printf "nilString evaluates to true" }}
{{- end -}}

{{- if not .Values.emptyString }}
{{ printf "not emptyString evaluates to true" }}
{{- end -}}

{{- if not .Values.nilString }}
{{ printf "not nilString evaluates to true" }}
{{- end -}}
```

Helm template output:

```
➜  helm template . --debug
install.go:173: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:190: [debug] CHART PATH: <REDACTED>

---
# Source: asd/templates/test.yaml
someEmptyString="abcdef")
emptyString="")
nilString=%!q(<nil>))
someString evaluates to true
not emptyString evaluates to true
not nilString evaluates to true
```

So yes, it should work if you use `{{ if $var.alias }}`

Answer (score 6):

1. Check if `MyKey` key exists and has non-empty values, i.e. not one of `0`, `false`, `""`, `null`:

```
{{- if .Values.MyKey }}
```

2. Check if `MyKey` key exists and its value is not null:

```
{{ if not (quote .Values.emptyString | empty)  }}
```

3. Check if `MyKey` key exists:

```
{{- if hasKey .Values "MyKey" }}
```

e.g.

```
MyKey: 5
```

returns true for 1, true for 2, true for 3

```
MyKey: false
```

returns false for 1, true for 2, true for 3

```
MyKey:
```

returns false for 1, false for 2, true for 3

```
DifferentKey:
```

returns false for 1, false for 2, false for 3

The same result applies to map and list as well.

The answer is inspired by following StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74732808/9749861

Answer (score 0):

i opt out for this to check and empty string:

```
{{- if eq .Values.MyemptyString "" }}
```

you can also use the below code to check non empty string:

```
{{- if not (eq .Values.notEmptyString "") }}
```