# Helm template check if boolean value is actually empty not false

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How to tell if a value, more specifically a boolean typed value is empty in a `gotpl` alias helm template?

How to tell if a simple value is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple options, how to tell if a normal (not boolean) value is empty.

A very brute force and quite long way is to put an if statement around your node such as

```
{{ if .Values.simpleText }}
isEmpty: false
{{ end }}
```

This will evaulate `isEmpty` as `false` only if there is any value inside `.Values.simpleText`

A better way to do this is to use the inbuilt `empty` function:

```
isEmpty2: {{ empty .Values.simpleText }}
```

> This does the same as the first example just shorter and arguably more
> readable

**The issue** with theese methods is that if you have a node which is a bool theese methods wont work.

```
#values.yaml
myBool: false
#-----------------------------------------
#template.yaml
isBoolEmpty: {{ empty .Values.myBool }}
#-----------------------------------------
#output
isBoolEmpty: true
```

> This will claim that `.Values.myBool` is empty even tho it clearly has
> a value which is false.

Now there is an option to check if a value is nil

```
isNil: {{ eq nil .Values.nilValue }}
```

> This will result as true if the value is indeed nil ( `nilValue:` ) but as soon as you have a value inside `nilValue` you will get a type exception.

**The solution** that I found and seemed the easiest to understand and to use is:

```
{{ if (quote .Values.myBool | empty)  }}
isActuallyEmpty: ".Values.myBool is empty"
{{ else }}
isActuallyEmpty: ".Values.myBool has a false or true value"
{{ end }}
```

I am sorry if this is very trivial but I know that I was struggleing with this question for some time.

Comment: It's a brilliant solution! Thx for sharing it.